# Could not find json-2.3.0

Tags: bundle-install

when i run metasploit there found some error like that...

[i] Database already started
[i] The database appears to be already configured, skipping initialization
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated

Could not find json-2.3.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

i also tried -> bundle install
-> apt-get install json-2.3.0

root@kali:~# bundle install
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:29: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:30: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:10: warning: constant Gem::ConfigMap is deprecated
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root
users on this machine.
Could not locate Gemfile

#anyone can help me!!!